# jQuery.ajax: TypeError: Property 'xhr' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a jquery.ajax object in which I want to substitute xhr. However executing the following code gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Property 'xhr' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

The relevant code is:

```
    var req = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    req.upload.addEventListener('progress', calendar.check_progress, false);

    $.ajax({
        url: script_root + '_save_file/'+id+'/'+timestamp,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: fd,
        xhr: req,
        success: function(data){
            do_something();
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            do_something_else();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ajax method has no function by name xhr: req .. this is messing up your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xhr` is used in other way. See documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> xhr: Function
>
> Default: ActiveXObject when available (IE), the XMLHttpRequest
>   otherwise
>
> Callback for creating the XMLHttpRequest object. Defaults to the
>   ActiveXObject when available (IE), the XMLHttpRequest otherwise.
>   Override to provide your own implementation for XMLHttpRequest or
>   enhancements to the factory.

May be you're looking for something like

```
xhr: function() {
    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', calendar.check_progress, false);
    return myXhr;
},
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();`? Seems to be a _typo_.